MongoDB recursion
I am trying to create a deep folder structure where there is a parentFolder and subFolder relationship, so I came up with this
import folderSchema from "@/models/folderSchema";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (req, res) => {
  const orgId = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("organizationId");
  try {
    // Fetch all root folders (folders without parent folders)
    const rootFolders = await folderSchema
      .find({
        organization: orgId,
        parentFolders: { $size: 0 }, // No parent folder, indicating root
      })
      .select("folderName subfolders")
      .populate({
        path: "subfolders",
        select: "folderName subfolders", // Selecting subfolder name and nested subfolders
        populate: {
          path: "subfolders", // Recursively populate subfolders
          select: "folderName subfolders",
          populate: {
            path: "subfolders", // Continue recursion for deeper levels
            select: "folderName subfolders",
          },
        },
      })
      .lean();

    return NextResponse.json({ data: rootFolders });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching folders with subfolders:", error);
    // throw error;
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Something went wrong" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};

Now the issue with this method is that it does not recursively populate the folderName for deeper subfolders, which means I will have to hardcode the populate function multiple times, which is still not good, incase a user have a deeper structure.
I then came up with another method, which required me to create a recursive helper function, but that was just a mess, as it was just another endless loop
const recrsivelyPopulateDeepFolders = async (folder) => {
  if (!folder || !folder.subfolders || folder.subfolders.length === 0) {
    return folder;  }

  await folder.populate({
    path: "subfolders",
    select: "folderName subfolders",
  });

  await Promise.all(
    folder.subfolders.map(async (subfolder) => {
      await recrsivelyPopulateDeepFolders(subfolder);
    })
  );

  return folder;
};

and then, I used this function like this
  try {
    // Fetch all root folders (folders without parent folders)
    const rootFolders = await folderSchema
      .find({
        organization: orgId,
        parentFolders: { $size: 0 }, // No parent folder, indicating root
      })
      .select("folderName subfolders");

    // Recursively populate all subfolders for each root folder
    const populatedFolders = await Promise.all(
      rootFolders.map(async (folder) => {
        return recrsivelyPopulateDeepFolders(folder);
      })
    );

    return NextResponse.json({ data: populatedFolders });
  } catch

but this didnt work, and it kept looping indefinitely
I also used the $graphLookUp function from mongoDb, but all it did was just display the root folder, then displayed all subfolders directly under the root folders and all nested subfolders inside the subfolders and so on, all at once, which does not achieve the deep folder structure I want
const rootFolders = await folderSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      organization: orgId,
      parentFolders: { $size: 0 }, // Fetch only root folders
    },
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "folders",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "parentFolders",
      as: "subfolders", 
      depthField: "depth", 
      maxDepth: 10, 
    },
  },
]);

I want to achieve this structure
[
  {
    "_id": "66eea89b28229934e8a98a1c",
    "folderName": "Folder 1",
    "subfolders": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "66eea8ae28229934e8a98a3f",
    "folderName": "Folder 6",
    "subfolders": [
      {
        "_id": "66eea8aa28229934e8a98a38",
        "folderName": "Folder 5",
        "subfolders": [
          {
            "_id": "66eea8a728229934e8a98a31",
            "folderName": "Folder 4",
            "subfolders": [
              {
                "_id": "66eea8a328229934e8a98a2a",
                "folderName": "Folder 3",
                "subfolders": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "66eea89f28229934e8a98a23",
                "folderName": "Folder 2",
                "subfolders": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "66eea8b628229934e8a98a4d",
        "folderName": "Folder 8",
        "subfolders": [
          {
            "_id": "66eea8aa28229934e8a98a38",
            "folderName": "Folder 5",
            "subfolders": [
              {
                "_id": "66eea8a728229934e8a98a31",
                "folderName": "Folder 4",
                "subfolders": [
                  "66eea8a328229934e8a98a2a",
                  "66eea89f28229934e8a98a23"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "66eea8b228229934e8a98a46",
    "folderName": "Folder 7",
    "subfolders": [
      {
        "_id": "66eea8ba28229934e8a98a54",
        "folderName": "Folder 9",
        "subfolders": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "66eea8be28229934e8a98a5b",
    "folderName": "Folder 10",
    "subfolders": [
      {
        "_id": "66eea8aa28229934e8a98a38",
        "folderName": "Folder 5",
        "subfolders": [
          {
            "_id": "66eea8a728229934e8a98a31",
            "folderName": "Folder 4",
            "subfolders": [
              {
                "_id": "66eea8a328229934e8a98a2a",
                "folderName": "Folder 3",
                "subfolders": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "66eea89f28229934e8a98a23",
                "folderName": "Folder 2",
                "subfolders": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


As ray mentioned in the staging ground, Your desired structure is an anti-pattern and you should be using $graphLookup. Read the example docs for how to Model Tree Structures.
